# yt-dlp pass multiple urls in one query

Tags: python, yt-dlp

I'm using yt-dlp to parse youtube video info with yt_dlp.extract_info(url). But yt_dlp.extract_info(url) takes only one url per query.

I'm tried to implement it like this, but getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object with urls
and
yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unsupported URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=567,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=789 with urls_2

```
import yt_dlp

urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=567']
urls_2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=567'
ydl_opts = {'skip_download': True}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(urls)
```

Is there any way to make it work like this without creating playlist on youtube?